# Deleting one of 2 pointers that point to the same thing

Tags: c++

So i have an array of pointers that point to objects, and a pointer that points to each object elsewhere in my code. What i want is when i delete those other pointer. How do i rearrange my array of pointers so that there's no garbage values in the middle of it. I have a rearrange function that checks for NULL but the pointer doesn't point to NULL.

```
void Floor::rearrange(){
    for (int i=0;i<numEnemies;i++){
            if(Enemies[i] == NULL){
                    Enemies[i] = Enemies[i+1];
                    Enemies[i+1] = NULL;
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Use automatically owning pointers. `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `unique_ptr` can automatically solve this problem for you with correct usage.

Using `delete` is a major code smell.

Comment: delete can be fine to use when you can guarantee single ownership for the heap objects lifetime

Comment: @foips, correct use of `unique_ptr` guarantees that for you using the type system, with no overhead.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the pointers in the array to be `weak_ptr` then the other pointers should be `shared_ptr`.

That way,  when the other pointer is deleted you can safely detect it.